# Sorting array by multiple columns/keys with array_multisort

Tags: php, array-multisort

How can I sort array elements below?

Each array item in dRows or cRows needs to be sorted by date (oldest first), acc (asc), am (asc) using array_multisort?

I tried using array_multisort in foreach and without foreach but it doesn't do anything and it wont sort it

```
[1000] => Array
        (
            [dRows] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [acc] => 100
                            [am] => 100.00
                            [date] => 2016-04-27
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [acc] => 100
                            [amount] => 130.80
                            [date] => 2016-04-27
                        )

                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [acc] => 101
                            [amount] => 30.80
                            [date] => 2016-04-26
                        )

                )

            [cRows] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [acc] => 200
                            [amount] => 100.00
                            [date] => 2016-06-25
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [acc] => 201
                            [amount] => 130.80
                            [date] => 2016-06-25
                        )

                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [acc] => 200
                            [amount] => 30.80
                            [date] => 2016-04-27
                        )

                    [3] => Array
                        (
                            [acc] => 200
                            [amount] => 30.80
                            [date] => 2016-04-26
                        )

                )
        )
```

Comment: How you getting this data.. I mean by `SELECT` query or anything else...?

Comment: From database query but after this there are lot of logic involved when creating this array and it is pretty impossible to change it there because of some other things :(

Comment: Means you can't do it in Query like `ORDER BY date asc`...?

Comment: I can't. I tried that at first but because of all other logic involved and creating new array it goes too far away and "order by" in query doesn't change too much :(